# random variables and dynamical systems

Tags: random-variable

Dynamical systems have two parts: the state (usually a vector), and the rule (usually a matrix) such that the vector and matrix are compatible. Often enough I have seen how dynamical systems are represented as deterministic equations.

What I haven't seen dynamical systems expressed in terms of random variables. I would like to know if any of you have worked with these. I am interested to know how properties like eigenvalues behave. (I'm sure they will also have distributions, just like the random variables). Stability of the matrix would be interesting to study, too.

Any insights would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Random variables that are functions of time are called [stochastic processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process). A stochastic process can be, but doesn't have to be described as dynamical (i.e. the future arising from the past via a rule), and they are not limited to time as the independent variable (see [random field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_field)).

For discrete states and discrete time, a typical form to describe a dynamical stochastic process is a [Markov process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), whose dynamics are described by transition probabilities between states from one time point to the next. For continuous states and discrete time, a typical form to describe linear dynamics are [autoregressive processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), where the next state is a linear combination of previous states plus noise. For continuous states and continuous time, which is probably closest to what you are familiar with in deterministic dynamics, a stochastic process may be described by a stochastic differential equation or [Langevin equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation).

A dynamics that is stochastic with respect to the system states can alternatively be described as a dynamics that is deterministic with respect to the probability distribution over states. For the Langevin equation this representation leads to the [Fokker–Planck equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation), for discrete states and continuous time to the [Master equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation).

Stochastic and deterministic dynamics are not completely separate. One the one side, deterministic dynamics can be understood as the limiting case of stochastic dynamics for vanishing noise amplitude; on the other side, it may prove useful to characterize deterministic (maybe chaotic) dynamics in terms of the evolution of distributions over state space (see e.g. [Probabilistic Properties of Deterministic Systems](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/probabilistic-properties-deterministic-systems)). Moreover, "noise" can be [considered](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stochastic_dynamical_systems#Noise_as_chaos) as the result of coupling to a very large (very high-dimensional) deterministic dynamical system whose state evolution cannot be tracked in detail.

Be aware that this answer can only be a tiny overview over a vast field.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the breadth of your response. Right now I solving a problem that is concerned about the stability of a particular system. It can be written as a recursion relation and ultimately into a matrix-vector form (ala dynamical systems). That's why I asked the question. 

I am not familiar with stochastic processes. I only know them by name and by form, but I have not worked with them formally. Would there be a way to explore convergence issues using stochastic processes? I would be interested in these.

Comment: @cgo, I can think of two forms of convergence for stochastic processes, 1) the probability distribution converges to a stable state, a stationary distribution (does not spread out all over phase space), or 2) as a special case, that probability distribution narrows down to a point (becomes a delta).

Comment: There was one thing I was confused about your question: For me, the standard form of a dynamical system is a system of ordinary differential equations (or a single vector-valued ODE). For linear dynamics this is a system of linear equations and can therefore be represented by a matrix. But I wouldn't say describing a dynamical system in matrix-vector form is standard. Maybe I misunderstand you? Can you give an example?

Comment: How about posting a question about the particular system you are working with?

Comment: Hi. A system of ODE's are usual examples of a dynamical system. You did not misunderstand me actually, and what you are thinking is actually correct. What I am interest is something like this: $\begin{cases} x_{t+1} & =& (1-cY)x_t + wv_t \\ v_{t+1} & = &-cYx_t + v_t\end{cases}$. In this case, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y \sim U(0,1)$. Also, $v$ is in *no way* construed as a velocity and $x$ as position. They can be any other variables. But they can be taken as 'states'. Notice that it CAN be written in the matrix-vector form (ala dynamical systems), and I'm interested in the matrix stability.

Comment: I also understand the analysis via probability density functions. I have already done that, and I have proven that for certain values of $c$, the distribution converges to delta distribution. Since this has been done already, what other properties would you suggest we look into?

Comment: Ok, you're thinking of discrete time, therefore iteration equations, and the equations are linear in the variables. The simplest stochastic form would be additive noise, which leads to an autoregressive process, but you have multiplicative noise. What would be typical values of $w$ and $c$?

Comment: Usual values according to literature would be $w \in [0.4, 0.9]$ and $c=2$. These are values that are not derived analytically, but are simulated again and again.

Comment: @cgo, interesting, but I have to say I never worked with such a system. Your dynamics is described by a [random matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix), but I think random matrix theory is more concerned with the case where every element is random, and identically distributed. Still, maybe there is something.

Comment: The long-term evolution of the system is described by powers of this matrix, so the interesting question is what the distribution of the eigenvalues of the matrix tells us about the distribution of the eigenvalues of matrix powers (which is not necessarily a distribution of powers of eigenvalues). That's roughly the direction I would go, but as I said, I have no concrete experience.

Comment: Indeed yes, some elements of my matrix are random, though some are deterministic. Indeed the eigenvalues will have distributions. Many thanks for your insights.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.